# Don't know how to take this "ghost" effect

Tags: blender

When I'm modeling, pretty much pulling vertices, it starts to show this kinda ghostly effect around the mesh, I didn't activated anything only the mirror.

I tried everything, like reseting the Normals, making things smooth, looking for answers on the internet but nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ghost" mesh you see is from a [subdivision surface modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html) (subsurf), the solid mesh is the end result while the ghost mesh is the original mesh that you are editing.

At the top of each modifier, you will find three or four buttons that control visibility. For the subsurf modifier, the third will show the original and the subsurf mesh while in edit mode, and the fourth will deform the edit mesh to the final shape.

[image: subsurf visibility options]